# How to mirror list elemets over the last element?

Tags: python

How can I mirror list elements across 0 using a list comprehension?
My `for`-loop code is below.

```
def mirror_list(max, increment):  
    lst = [-max]  
    while lst[-1] < max:  
        lst.append(lst[-1] + increment)  
    lst[-1] = max  
    return lst
```

For instance, `mirror_list(10, 2)` would return `[-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = [x for x in range(-top, top+1, increment)]
```

`max` is a built-in function, so I changed the name to `top`.

Note that this assumes that `increment` is a divisor of `top`; this is required to properly land on 0.

Comment: The use of `range` is brilliant!